# Get all fields names from a Symfony's Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

For a project I need to check if all form's fields are present in a **`PUT`** request.

Simple data validation with the `NotNull` / `NotBlank` constraints **is not appropriate** because the fields in the request **can** be set with `NULL` or blank values **but** they have to be present.

My idea is to take all names from a Form's field and check if those fields are present in the request array.

To do the trick I **need to get names of those fields**, there's an array in the Form class named `orderedKeys` which contains exactly what I want, **but** the variable is set to **`private`**.

**Is there any other way to get access to those keys ?**

Comment: use the $form->getData() inside your controller after the form is submitted and check if all field inside are correct , but with the check $form->isValid() all field should be as expected, using formtype also can be better to give default values to the fields you want. Inside the $request also you have those fields $request->request->get('yourfield');

Comment: The getData function returns the object "molded" by the form, I don't see how this can help me. The isValid function doesn't check if all form's fields are present.

And I do not want to put default values to fields.

What I want is to be able to check the Request object and see if all the form's fields are present, if not I will send a Bad Request Exception and ask the user to fill the form properly for a PUT request.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get all the child forms of a form by doing

```
$form->all();
```

Then you can recover the name of each field by doing

```
$child->getName();
```