# Symfony: Get parent object within child from formevent

Tags: symfony, event-listener, dynamic-forms

I have a form that contains 3 fields (date, typeEvent, seller) where Seller is a choiceType that depends on **date** and **typeEvent**, and to do that i followed [the symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) for dynamics forms.
but the exemple in the doc its about a field that depends on only one other field.

what i did so far :

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form,DateTime  $date = null, TypeEvent $type = null) {
            if (($date === null) || ($type === null)) {$sellers = [];return;}
            $repo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
            $start = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $end = new DateTime($date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            $end = date_add($end,date_interval_create_from_date_string("60 minutes"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $organisation = $this->security->getUser()->getOrganisation();
            $sellers = $repo->findSellers($organisation,$start,$end);
            $form->add('seller', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $sellers,
                'choice_label' => 'pseudo',
                'attr' => ['class'=>'seller-select'],
                'required'=>false,
                'expanded' =>false,
            ]);
        };

        $builder->get('start')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $start = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $type = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()->getTypeEvent();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $start, $type);
            }
        );
        $builder->get('typeEvent')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $type = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $start = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()->getStart();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $start, $type);
            }
        );
```

the problem here is that, for exemple when i try to add a listener to 'start' field inside of it, i don't have access to the other fields, the typeEvent field specifically, i tried $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData()->getTypeEvent() but it returns null, and that's $event->getForm()
[dumped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUcQd.png)

As you can see the $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData() it's like a new Event() with all attribute on null.
So my question is: There is any way to get the typeEvent there ? or should i proceed differently?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this is what you want, but you should take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25890150/17089665

`$form->all();` <- Will get you all fields

`$child->getName();` <- Will get you the name of every child, if you iterate the `$form` variable.

Comment: the point is how to access to the form ^^'.

Comment: Isn't `$event->getForm()` working?

Comment: no cause, the listener is on a child ('start') and not the form, so $event->getForm() returns the start form, if you go back to my code you gonna see that i tried  to get to the parent form (wich is the form you talking about) by  using $event->getForm()->getParent() but i got an empty data as you can see in the image

Comment: Can you please post a dump of $event?

Comment: https://ibb.co/6J23f1H

Comment: So, if your event has a parent, can't you just use `$event->getParent()->getForm()` instead of `$event->getForm()->getParent()`?

Comment: $event is a FormEvent that has no method getParent, its the FormInterface who got that method, if you wanna go deeper on that issue, here is my gmail hop.gangnam.style@gmail.com , cause there is a limit of comments, thank you.

Comment: Try with pre-submit. I am sorry that I couldn't help you further